# Параметр процедуры SQL

Tags: sql

Здравствуйте! Создаю процедуру

```
CREATE PROCEDURE aaa
@god as date
AS
SELECT ---
FROM  ---
WHERE DataPerevoda=YEAR (@god)
```

Вылазит следующая ошибка:

> `Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int`

Мне нужно из даты перевода вытащить только код, YEAR ([[[@god](/users/56/god)](/users/56/god)](/users/56/god)) не срабатывает...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHERE YEAR(DataPerevoda) =YEAR ([@god](/users/56/god))

Comment: точно, спасибо!